# How can we generate auto increment invoice #

Tags: php, auto-increment, invoices

```
   $runningnumber=1;
   $comp = "CT";
   echo $result = $comp.date('mdy').str_pad($runningnumber++, 5, "0", 
   STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

how do i increase the $runnungnumber like 00001, 00002, 00003, 00004, 00005, 00006 .... please help

my desired output is

```
CT08221700001
CT08221700002
CT08221700003
CT08221700004
CT08221700005
```

Comment: And what is your output right now?

Comment: i am using PHP, and my output is CT08221700001 but i don't know how to increase the value of $runningnumber on page load .. so after pageload the value will be CT08221700002 .. everytime on page load the value will be increase

Comment: Because `$runningnumber` is a variable it's value is reseted at every request. You will need to store that number in something else, like a file or a database.

Comment: plz give some hint so i can understand how it will be done

Comment: Read about file input/output in PHP or about SQL and how to setup a database (like MySQL, MariaDB, SQLite) it's easier than you think.

Comment: <?php    
         $query="SELECT ct_inv_id FROM ct_sale_invo ORDER BY ct_inv_id DESC LIMIT 1;";
         $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
         $runningnumber=@$row["ct_inv_id"];
         $runningnumber++;
         $compcode = "CT";
         echo $result = $compcode.date('mdy').str_pad($runningnumber++, 5, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
      ?>

Comment: i use this approach and its working magically fine ..